# Ухудшение качества иконки после сборки проекта

Tags: c#, wpf, иконки

Сделал случайную иконку, выглядит она вот так (Скриншот с рабочего стола):

[image: Сделанная иконка]

После этого добавил ее в проект, через *Проект > Свойства > Ресурсы > Значек и манифест* привязал к проекту, на выходе получается exe с такой иконкой:

[image: Иконка на выходе]

Наглядное сравнение (слева собранный проект, справа оригинал):

[image: Сравнение]

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: Исходная иконка какое имеет разрешение и глубину цвета?

Comment: *ровный* вид это результат работы сглаживания, на самом деле ваша иконка именно такая *зубчатая*; отдельно для иконки его включить вряд ли получиться, только для всей формы `SnapsToDevicePixels = false; UseLayoutRounding = true;` вроде.

Comment: @АндрейNOP 128х128, 32 - глубина цвета

Comment: Скорее всего у иконки был изменён размер, потому как 128 не поддерживается. Посмотрите этот пост: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244679/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP сменил разрешение на 256х256. Все равно, оригинал более сглаженный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, я понял, чем это вызвано. Похоже, что ни PhotoShop с ущербным плагином "ICOFormat.8bi", ни Gimp не сохраняли файлы нормально.

С помощью Axialis IconWorkshop я смог нормально конвертировать файл в ico и потом вставить в программу. Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая - изначальная, вторая - сконвертированная при помощи Axialis IconWorkshop, третья - уже exe файл.